# Adding multiple Kendo windows with a text area

Tags: javascript, html, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a small window with a text area inside every time the click of a button happens. However when I click the button more than once, a new window is created but only the first window contains the text area. Can anyone help?

```
var noteNumber = 0;

$("#createNoteButton").click(function () {

    var noteWindowDivId = "noteWindow" + noteNumber;
    $("<div id=noteWindowDivId />").appendTo(document.body).kendoWindow ({
        draggable: true, resizable: true, width: "480px",
        height: "100px", title: "Note",
        scrollable: false,
        modal: false, actions: ["Close"]
    });
    $("#noteWindowDivId").data("kendoWindow").content("<textarea id=noteNumber style='width: 100%; height: 100%'> </textarea>");
    noteNumber++;
}
);
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong. you should have your content hidden and window hidden. on click event 1) add content("get content") 2)make you window visible and 3)call window.open()

Comment: Thanks, thats the original way I had the rest of my windows but management wanted only the windows stored in the users preferences loaded on page load. So this isnt an option for me.